# Android Emulator inside docker container surfaceflinger crashing endldess boot loop

Tags: android, docker, sdk, android-emulator, surfaceflinger

I'm trying to setup some android automation in cloud (Docker in specific).

Here is my docker file:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN echo "debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | debconf-set-selections && \
    echo "debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true" | debconf-set-selections

# Update packages
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&\
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get install -qqy \
        software-properties-common\
        curl \
        html2text \
        libc6-i386 \
        lib32stdc++6 \
        lib32gcc1 \
        lib32ncurses5 \
        bzip2 \
        lib32z1 \
        unzip \
        wget \
        build-essential \
        expect \
        file \
        libmagic1 \
        python-pip && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install oracle-java8-installer && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Install android sdk

RUN wget -q -O /tmp/sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3952940.zip \
    && unzip -q /tmp/sdk.zip -d /usr/local/android-sdk \
    && rm /tmp/sdk.zip \
    && chown -R root:root /usr/local/android-sdk/

# Add android tools and platform tools to PATH
ENV ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/android-sdk
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/bin
# AMULATOR NEEDS THIS ENV
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT $ANDROID_HOME

ENV QEMU_AUDIO_DRV none

# Export JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

## accept license
RUN mkdir -p $ANDROID_HOME/licenses
RUN echo '8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55' > $ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license

RUN sdkmanager --update
RUN sdkmanager 'platform-tools'
RUN sdkmanager 'tools'
RUN sdkmanager 'platforms;android-22'
RUN sdkmanager 'lldb;2.3'
RUN sdkmanager 'emulator'
RUN sdkmanager 'build-tools;22.0.1'

# Extras
RUN sdkmanager 'extras;android;m2repository'
RUN sdkmanager 'extras;google;m2repository'
RUN sdkmanager 'extras;google;google_play_services'

RUN sdkmanager 'extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2'
RUN sdkmanager 'extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.1'

RUN sdkmanager 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22'
# RUN sdkmanager 'system-images;android-22;google_apis_playstore;x86'
# No KVM required image
RUN sdkmanager 'system-images;android-22;google_apis;armeabi-v7a'
RUN sdkmanager 'system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a'

# Create fake keymap file
RUN mkdir /usr/local/android-sdk/tools/keymaps && \
    touch /usr/local/android-sdk/tools/keymaps/en-us

# EMULATOR
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yqq update && apt-get install -y libqt5widgets5
ENV QT_QPA_PLATFORM offscreen
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/
```

I create avd using this command:

```
avdmanager create avd --name avdtest --force --package 'system-images;android-24;google_apis;armeabi-v7a' --abi 'google_apis/armeabi-v7a' --tag 'google_apis'
```

Running emulator using this command:

```
/emulator/emulator -avd avdtest -writable-system -engine classic -no-window -camera-back none -camera-front none -debug all -qemu -m 512
```

Using this setup I cannot run avd getting error:

```
  I/DEBUG   (   61): Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:5.1.1/LMY48X/4088218:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   61): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   61): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (   61): pid: 1844, tid: 1844, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   (   61): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (   61):     r0 00000000  r1 00000734  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   61):     r4 b6f5ce38  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (   61):     r8 ffffffc4  r9 b648d158  sl 00000000  fp bebc4b7c
I/DEBUG   (   61):     ip 00000734  sp bebc4998  lr b6eb9745  pc b6edc950  cpsr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   61):
I/DEBUG   (   61): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #00 pc 00039950  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #01 pc 00016741  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #02 pc 0001735f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #03 pc 00013b39  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #04 pc 00012f18  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #05 pc 000214ff  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #06 pc 00017841  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+104)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #07 pc 00000af1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #08 pc 00012dc9  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
I/DEBUG   (   61):     #09 pc 00000c08  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (   61):
I/DEBUG   (   61): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running an emulator image on a Linux (Ubuntu) VM, running on a Windows 10 host. I got this problem with the SurfaceFlinger crashing and the device never seemed to start up. I tried lots of suggestions, but eventually I tried the suggestions in these two articles:

https://www.jc-tech.info/2018/04/10/android-emulator-crashing-due-to-access-violation/
https://www.jc-tech.info/2017/07/12/android-emulator-hanging-with-black-screen/

I think changing to the SwiftShader (see the first link) got passed the crashing, and by deliberately choosing hardware acceleration I got a visible emulator homescreen. HOWEVER, this latter may just have been because I waited longer, or used an emulator image with more memory (both were true) and I haven't tested without them. I don't know how you could choose the SwiftShader from the command line. If you figure out how, please post it here. I'd love to know! In any case, since you're running with "-no-window", the switch to SwiftShader may be all you need.

In case you can't do it from the command line, you could probably create one with the desired attributes and copy that into your docker image when you're building it.

EDIT: I still haven't tried this in a container, but to run it from the command line as opposed to using Android Studio in my Ubuntu VM I needed to add "-gpu host" to the emulator command. I don't think the SwiftShader is necessary after all as it's a software renderer.